# Решение систем линейных уравнений

Tags: python, алгоритм

Пытаюсь решить систему линейных выражений.
F - большой массив из разных цифр
F_left- левая часть
f_right - правая

```
f_right = np.array([65,71,77,73])#73
F_left = np.zeros((4,4))
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        F_left[i][j] = F[i+301][j+150]

print("F_left")
#ans is [-1.81003397e+19  1.62704034e+19  3.19253235e+19 -7.54955293e+18]
```

Изображение матрицы F_left
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
M1 = np.array([[-0.61113457, -0.74659126, 0.23822642,0.86360848], [0.61724912, 0.75406108, -0.24060993,-0.87224909], [-0.02221076, -0.02713373, 0.00865798,0.03138654],[-0.59168172,-0.72282672,0.2306435,0.8361192]]) # Матрица (левая часть системы)
np.linalg.solve(M1, f_right)
#ans is [-1.95854204e+10 -1.36793266e+11 -1.85296035e+11 -8.10038054e+10]
```

Решает и выдает правильный ответ
Подскажите, почему в 1 варианте выдает неправильный ответ.

Comment: Чсил обсловленности уже проходили?  Это тот самый случай.

Comment: Получается у меня плохо обусловленная матрица?) @Chorkov

Comment: Да (`numpy.linalg.cond( M1 ) = 8.e9`), причем вы выписали всего 9 знаков после запятой..  Если вывести все 18 значащих цифр, то число  обусловленности, наверняка, еще поднимется.